# Настройка автозапуска программы с правами администратора

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, windows

**Проблема:** есть программа, написанная на c#. Нужно сделать так,чтобы она висела в автозагрузке с правами администратора, однако запустить программу при включении пк с запросом в файле манифеста:

`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>`

не представляется возможным из-за UAC. Пробовал добавлять в папку автозагрузки, в реестр по пути текущего пользователя и local machine, создавал таск при включение пк. Ничего не вышло, при запуске программа даже не пытается запустится.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы программа при запуске один раз попросила права администратора, и далее была в автозагрузке с правами админа. Или легче ли обойти uac?

Comment: Подразумевается запуск уже готового экзешника

Comment: @rp88imxo IMXO программа с гуём?

Comment: гуй скрывается удаленно, Visibility="Hidden | Visible", гуй на wpf

Comment: Используйте планировщик заданий.

Comment: @rp88imxo IMXO юзер гуй может увидеть? если нет то делайте службу

Comment: @PetSerAI Писал же в теме, что создание таска так же не решает проблему.

Comment: @Vasek хорошая идея, однако пользователь при первом запуске видит гуй, и может настроить, чтобы последующие запуски были в фоне. Или это в принципе глупо так организовать программу, и лучше сделать ее изначально в виде службы?

Comment: @rp88imxo IMXO ну обычно в таких случаях делают службу и в довесок к ней програмку настройщик

Comment: @Vasek почему не ответом? Это действительно распространенная практика. А если в службу запихнуть WCF сервис для интерактивного управления, вообще красота получается, голая-то служба практически не управляется извне старт-стоп и все по большому счету, ну конфиги еще с последующим перезапуском.

Comment: @rdorn ответ сделать можно, но это будет не совсем ответ на этот конкретный вопрос. Поэтому если автор не запросит, лучше оставить как есть